# Number of prime ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

In a certain exercise I am asked to find all prime ideals of the ring $\mathbb{R}[x]/I$, where $I = \left <(x^2-1)^5\right>$. I know that if $p(x)$ is divisible by $x-1$ or $x+1$, then $p(x)$ does not generate a prime ideal in this case. However, I guess that there are infinite prime ideals of this ring, that is why I suspect something is wrong. How can I continue?

Comment: Because $\Bbb{R}[x]$ is a PID, every ideal of $\Bbb{R}[x]/I$ is principal. Do you see why that follows? Another  key ingredient is the Chinese remainder theorem. Has that been covered in this context?

Comment: The first fact I know it. I don't know thow to use the Chinese remainder theorem.

Comment: You can also think of it as follows. By the divisibility theory of $\Bbb{R}[x]$, the ideals of $\Bbb{R}[x]/I$ have the form $J/I$, where $J$ is an ideal containing $I$. In other words, the generator of $J$ needs to be a factor of $(x^2-1)^5$. All factors give ideals, and your task is to figure out which factors have the property that $J/I$ is a prime ideal.

Comment: That really helps me, thanks